# Is it bad idea to add nil as a subview?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Basically, I've created a custom view (extending `UIView`) that displays at least one image (but sometimes two, one on top of each other). The bottom image is a placeholder and since the image being placed on it can be deleted, I would like to be able to just remove the top image so the placeholder is visible again. I've created a message for placing an image on top of the placeholder (it removes and releases the last subview and adds the new one) and a message for showing the placeholder. During the course of this message `[self addSubview: nil]` will be called.

My questions are:

- Will `addSubview: nil` cause UB? Is it a bad idea?
- After adding `nil` as a subview, will it be added to the subviews array or will it be ignored?

Comment: Have you tried adding `nil` yourself before asking? It seems like a dumb idea, the subview cache in `UIView` header file is a `NSMutableArray`, so I have not tested but it probably will cause an invalid argument exception to add `nil`.

Comment: @PeyloW After posting this question, I tried this out in a project I had open. I first tried adding `nil` to a main view controller. It caused a SIGABRT on run but I'm guessing that was my code. Adding `nil` as a subview to the main window however caused no errors, but wasn't in the subviews array. I guess that's sort of the answer, but I'm still not sure if this will cause problems down the road.

Comment: @PeyloW In hindsight, I probably should have done that before posting. Good call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Is it really a good idea to add two image views to show the placeholder image and original image?**

Just ask yourself why do you want to have two image views separately to show the placeholder and the original image? You can have just one image view and show the placeholder image if the original image is not available meanwhile show the original image if it is available.

```
- (void)setMainImage:(UIImage *)mainImage {

    if (mainImage) self.mainImageView.image = mainImage;
    else self.mainImageView.image = thePlaceholderImage;
}
```

If you want to remove the main image, just call

```
[self setMainImage:nil];
```

Comment: Originally, I assumed it would be easier, however it seems fairly ridiculous now to go to all that trouble. I believe you have convinced me to just add one subview. Good show!